# My h:inputText value is not validated when it is bound to a field of some instance of a parametrized class gathered from a HashMap?

Tags: jsf-2, hashmap, validation, parameterized-constructor

I am trying to do some "custom lightweight" JSF component binding. In my bean (controlling some JSF page) i'm declaring a HahsMap where keys ranging over my `h:inputText` ids (appearing in the page) map these ids to custom `HInputText<T>` objects (`T` in the example given below is Long). Then i am using `HInputText<T>` objects to hold a subset of corresponding h:inputText attributes : `value` supposed to be of type `T`, `rendered`, `required`, etc. In this direction fields from the `HInputText<T>` objects give values to the `h:inputText` attributes.

My problem is that when using such an `h:inputText` inside a `h:form`, JSF validation does not take place : i can type alphanumeric chars in the `h:inputText` (supposed to hold a Long value) and my form submits without showing any errors. Note that `required` and `rendered` attributes are managed correctly (since `required` is set to true, i have an error when i leave the `h:inputText` field empty) and that when i try to display back the value of the `h:inputText` in the page using some `h:outputText` the alphanumeric chars are displayed.

Is there some trick to make JSF validation work without having to explicitly define a custom Validator for each `h:inputText`?

HInputText.class:

```
public class HInputText<T>
{
    private String id;
    private boolean rendered;
    private boolean required;
    private T value;
    private Class<T> myClass;

    // getters and setters for all fields

    public HInputText(Class<T> myClass, String id)
    {
        this.myClass = myClass;
        this.id = id;
        this.rendered = true;
        this.required = true;
    }
}
```

Code snippet from my Managed Bean :

```
@ManagedBean(name="saisieController")
@SessionScoped
public class SaisieController
{
    ...
    private HashMap<String,HInputText<Long>> htagLongInputTexts;

    public HashMap<String, HInputText<Long>> getHtagLongInputTexts()
    {
        return htagLongInputTexts;
    }

    public void setHtagLongInputTexts(HashMap<String, HInputText<Long>> hLongInputTexts)
    {
        this.htagLongInputTexts = hLongInputTexts;
    }

    public void addHtagLongInputText(HInputText<Long> hLongInputText)
    {
        getHtagLongInputTexts().put(hLongInputText.getId(), hLongInputText);
    }

    public HInputText<Long> getHtagLongInputText(String hLongInputTextId)
    {
        return(getHtagLongInputTexts().get(hLongInputTextId));
    }



    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        setHtagLongInputTexts(new HashMap<String, HInputText<Long>>());
        addHtagLongInputText(new HInputText<Long>(Long.class, "HIT_LongTestHIT"));
    }

    public String doNothing()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and finally a snippet from my jsf page:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText
        id = "HIT_LongTestHIT"
        value = "#{saisieController.htagLongInputTexts['HIT_LongTestHIT'].value}"
        rendered = "#{saisieController.htagLongInputTexts['HIT_LongTestHIT'].rendered}"
        required = "#{saisieController.htagLongInputTexts['HIT_LongTestHIT'].required}"
    />
    <h:message for = "HIT_LongTestHIT" styleClass = "error-text" />
    <h:commandButton value = "submit" action = "#{saisieController.doNothing()}" />
    <h:outputText value = "#{saisieController.htagLongInputTexts['HIT_LongTestHIT'].value}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Well, after further investigation i solved my problem by appending a converter : `<f:converter converterId = "javax.faces.Long" />` to the `h:inputText`. Indeed the type of `saisieController.htagLongInputTexts['HIT_LongTestHIT'].value` was curiously String and not Long as i was expecting. What i still do not understand (maybe i should read more JSF documentation) is why automatic validation perfectly works when the value of the `h:inputText` is set to some variable of type Long in the controller itself, but does in the case presented above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Is there some trick to make JSF validation work without having to explicitly define a custom Validator for each h:inputText?*

No, that's not possible. Due to *type erasure* the generic type information is not available during runtime. JSF/EL has no idea that `T` is actually a `Long`, let alone that there's actually *some* `T`. You really need to explicitly specify a converter which is in this particular example the [`LongConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/LongConverter.html) with a converter ID of [`javax.faces.Long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.convert.LongConverter.CONVERTER_ID).

```
<h:inputText ... converter="javax.faces.Long">
```

or, dynamically so you want

```
<h:inputText ...>
    <f:converter converterId="#{saisieController.htagLongInputTexts['HIT_LongTestHIT'].converterId}" />
</h:inputText>
```

You can find an overview of all available standard JSF converters in the [`javax.faces.convert` package summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/package-summary.html). You can find out their converter IDs by navigating to the *Constant field values* link on the public constant `CONVERTER_ID`.

Comment: Thanks a lot BalusC. This means that if i need only few type instances for T (let's say Long and BigDecimal) i can also define two non-paramterized `HInputText` classes, one per each type and auto-validation would work as charm.